# Is there a proper way to create a class that has only one instance and gets used in *almost* every file?

Tags: c++, game-development, header-files, sdl-2

I am creating a game with SDL2, and want to create a display class that contains data about the display that can be used by almost every file for example; I have a class x and class y whose functions use data (included from the same header) from the Display class, this data doesn't get modified, only used. And display is only initialized once (So that I don't need to create a new display class in each file, that would result in more than one window appearing.).

My game is already quite large, so I hope you will forgive me for writing very rough code as an example for what I have already tried:

(Assume correct SDL headers are included)

display.hpp file:

```
struct Display
{
    public:
        SDL_Renderer* renderer;
        int height; // height of display
        int width;
    
        Display(); // initializes private variables
};


Display display = Display();
```

main.cpp file:

```
#include "display.hpp"
#include "otherfile.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout << display.width << std::endl;
}
```

otherfile.cpp file:

```
function of class contained in otherfile.hpp that uses display
```

I actually expected the above code to work, but it through an error; I think about display being initialized in multiple files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: dont use a global, but rather create the instance in `main` and pass it to where it is needed. If you still use a global, look up "Meyers Singleton"

Comment: Why you don't want a global: It can be changed changed by anyone anywhere at any time. This is tolerable in a small program, but as they get bigger, having to suspect every line of code in the program for every bug related to the global quickly becomes unmanageable. Debugging and maintaining almost always take far longer than writing the program, so if you spend extra time on the short part of the job making sure the long part of the job takes less time, the overall time savings can be huge.

Comment: I cannot imagine you need your display to be available everywhere (in fact I think most of your code should not even bother with your display at all, seperation of concerns seperate logic from presentation). Make a small abstract baseclass for the data your other code needs and inject that. The approach you are taking now will not be maintainable (too closely coupled) and will not be unit testable. you do have unit tests do you? If not learn about dependency injection.